# LAN World won't show up on other computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to play on my singleplayer world with my sister. I have clicked <kbd>Add to LAN</kbd>, but it doesn't show up on her computer. We are on the same network and running the same version of Minecraft.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about playing Minecraft on multiplayer? If so, you need to add more information about what the exact problem you are having is.

Comment: Single player world with someone else... I think you want multiplayer over LAN

Comment: I am on a singleplayer world I want my sister to be able to join. I click add to LAN but it doesnt show up on her computer. We are on the same network and same edition of mc.

Answer (score 1):

"I know how"...  I will assume you are using "Open to LAN" in the pause (escape) menu.  I will also assume you are on a Windows computer.

1. If you are on Windows 8+, go to Search.  If you are on Windows 7, go to the Start menu.
2. Type in "cmd.exe".
3. Click on "cmd.exe" or "Command Prompt" (they're the same thing) when Windows finishes searching.
4. Type in "ipconfig" and press Enter.
5. Search the massive amount of letters and numbers for a number that generally starts with "192.168.0" or "192.168.1".  It is not 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 (those are usually your router/modem), so look for a different one.  Ex: 192.168.1.123
6. Copy and paste that number into Notepad (right-click, click on Mark, select the number, press Enter to copy) or write it down.
7. Type in "exit" and press Enter.
8. In Minecraft, go to the Pause menu -> Open to LAN...  You can change the options; it doesn't really matter.  Just click the Start LAN World button at the bottom.
9. In chat, there will probably be a message that's something like "Local game hosted on port 66666".  Copy and paste the number (in my example it's 66666) into Notepad or write it down.
10. On your sister's computer, go to Multiplayer -> Direct Connect.  She will want to type in the first thing you copied into Notepad (or wrote down) in step 5, followed by a colon (:), followed by the 5-digit number you wrote down in step 9.  Ex: 192.168.1.123:66666.  Finally, click Join Server at the bottom.  She should be in!

Good luck,

HewwoCraziness

Note: If you ever close the world you will have to repeat steps 8-10 as it will disconnect your sister also.  The five-digit number will change every time you close and reopen the world.  The longer number (Ex: 192.168.1.123) may change every week to every month to never, depending on your network setup.  In the event of that, just repeat steps 1-7.